# Spark ignore commas in string

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to load a csv via spark session but encountering issues with strings that contain double quotes and commas inside .i.e.

```
"""A"" STAR ACCOUNTING,& TRAINING SOLUTIONS LIMITED"
```

This creates the dataframe with 2 different columns based on the above string, outputs:

```
"""A"" STAR ACCOUNTING 
& TRAINING SOLUTIONS LIMITED"
```

Reading csv via spark session read csv

```
val df = ss.read
          .option("header", true)
          .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
          .csv(csvFile)
          .sort(id)
```

Anyway to read in a csv file and skip commas inside a string?

Comment: Can you post the command you're running?

Comment: How are you reading the file? The record is already enclosed in quotes to avoid delimiter collision. Use spark csv and you should be good

Comment: Edited with code that reads in csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your data use `"` as the escape character, while default value is `\`. You should provide `quote` option on read:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spark.read.option("escape", "\"").csv(Seq("\"\"\"A\"\" STAR ACCOUNTING,& TRAINING SOLUTIONS LIMITED").toDS).show(false)
+------------------------------------------------+
|_c0                                             |
+------------------------------------------------+
|"A" STAR ACCOUNTING,& TRAINING SOLUTIONS LIMITED|
+------------------------------------------------+
```